# MySQL Database optimization

Tags: mysql, optimization, count

I have a table which is frequently updated (insert/delete). I also have a script to periodically count how many records are stored in the table. How can I optimize the performance?

1. **Do nothing:** Just use the COUNT function.
2. **Create another field to store the number of records:** Whenever a new record's added, we increase that field and vice versa.

Comment: What is your table engine type ? innodb, myisam, memory ...?

Comment: Is `COUNT` **verified** to be too slow in this case? (There are *no performance numbers posted*, and thus I can only imagine this is a hypothetical question.) The denormalized approach is, well, denormalized .. besides containing duplicated data, an issue with an update could result in *incorrect information*.

Answer (score 3):

If your database's main function is storing (frequently inserting/updating), switch storage engine to `InnoDB`, which is faster with `INSERT` and `UPDATE` queries, but slower with reading.

Read more [here](http://www.kavoir.com/2009/09/mysql-engines-innodb-vs-myisam-a-comparison-of-pros-and-cons.html), [here](http://mikebernat.com/blog/MySQL_-_InnoDB_vs_MyISAM) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20148/myisam-versus-innodb).

Comment: is true that innodb has better performance in write, but look for count of a table rows is a READ.

Answer (score 0):

Method #2 is pretty much the standard way of doing it (if your table is incredibly huge and `COUNT` is giving you performance issues). You could also store the `COUNT` value in a [`MEMORY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/memory-storage-engine.html) table which would make retrieval exceedingly fast.

Increment/decrement as you see fit.

Comment: Yes, but ... not in this cause. As the objective is to count number of rows in a table without any filtering.

Comment: Sure it is. Not only that, but Postgres essentially does exactly this with its special sequence objects - sometimes storing sequences in the table itself (like mySQL does) will be a performance bottleneck as the OP is experiencing.

Comment: mysql already has a information schema to provide stats of row count for each table ... http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/tables-table.html (ps: works for myisam)

Comment: I didn't think `COUNT` used the `information_schema` since it always gives the correct number (isn't `information_schema` estimated?)

Comment: yup, that's my point, you DUN have to do count ... just seek the row count from information schema IF you are using myisam.

Answer (score 0):

If you need accurate numbers, I would build this into the app the updates the database or use triggers to keep the counts up to date.  As others have mentioned, the counts could be kept in a MEMORY table, or a Redis instance if you want performance and persistence.  There are counts in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES table, but they're not precise for InnoDB (+-20% or more).